convert bright field images to phase contrast or dic microscopy images (one of those three to any of those three)
Are there neural networks or other methods (machine learning-related I would assume) to convert bright field images to phase contrast or dic microscopy (one of those three to any of those three, ideally any of those transformations would be supported).
This would most likely involve doing different type of microscopy on exactly the same cells and then training a machine learning model so I don’t know if it has ever been done or if it even exists.

I highly doubt it; those are imaging techniques that result from the way light interacts with an object.
Faking it wouldn't be useful in the context of science as conversion won't tell you anything about the object (i.e, you can't get more information from an object than is already present in the image - this is a basic tenet of information science) and ethics would suggest that you need to declare the manipulation in any publication, so the value is low for any purpose other than entertainment.
